# Numbers default colors

Tags: numbers

The default grays in Numbers don't suit my needs (the gray is too dark). Is there any way to adjust this pallette? I always find myself diving into the colors palette but this gets time consuming and leads to inconsistent colors across my documents.

[image: Numbers colors]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the colours in the default palette. Once you have set a cell to your preferred colour, drag the new colour from **Current Fill** to one of the palette slots:

[image: Dragging custom colour from Current Fill to palette]

This will replace the colour in the palette:

[image: Palette showing new colour]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make infinite custom color choices. Click on the color swatch wheel below the color fill drop down menu:

[image: COLOR PALLET]